My WiFi card works at first in Linux but then suddenly stops working until I reboot again
I have had this issue with my Geekom mini-pc as well, and now I'm seeing this in my MSI MAG Tomahawk x870 motherboard with Qualcomm PCI card. I installed PopOS! and everything worked great, until after about 20 minutes to 1 hour in, the Wifi would suddenly stop working.
System Details:

Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS "jammy"
Kernel: 6.9
Qualcomm Wifi Chipset: NCM865
Driver: ath12k_pci

Things I have tried:

Modified /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf to disable powersave
Disable ufw
Disable wireguard
Disable tailscale
Turn off Bluetooth
Update ath12k_pci drivers: https://wireless.docs.kernel.org/en/latest/en/users/drivers/ath12k/installation.html

None of this has worked, and I'm out of ideas.

I finally tried updating the kernel using mainline and this seems to have worked. Now, I'm seeing stable WiFi connection.
Here's the guide I followed:

https://linuxhint.com/update-linux-kernel-pop-os/
https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

Steps:

Install mainline
Check if there's newer kernels available: mainline check
Update to the newest kernel: mainline install-latest

In my case, this was 6.12.1



